# How to get click event on particular option of select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectbox

I have a select dropdown like:

```
<select multiple="" id="search_skills" name="search_skills[]">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">PHP</option>
    <option value="2">JAVA</option>
    <option value="3">.NET</option>
</select>
```

Now when a user selects "All" first all the values should be selected. So I want a click event for that.
Here is what I am trying.but it's not working.

```
$(function(){ 
  $("select[name='search_skills[]']").change(function() {            
    if ( $("select[name='search_skills[]']")[0].selectedIndex === 0 ) {
        var sel_val = $("#search_skills").val();
        alert(sel_val);
        if(sel_val == 'all'){
            $("#search_skills > option").prop("selected","selected");
        }
        else if(sel_val.indexOf('all') == '-1'){
            $("#search_skills > option").removeAttr("selected");
        }
        $('#search_skills').selectpicker('refresh');
     }
  });
});
```

Please help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eanhhwoc/3/ - what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$('#selectall').click(function() {
    $('option').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" id="search_skills" name="search_skills[]">
    <option id="selectall" value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">PHP</option>
    <option value="2">JAVA</option>
    <option value="3">.NET</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `prop()` function:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#search_skills option[value="all"]', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var opt = $('#search_skills > option');
  if (!that.is('selected')) {
    opt.prop('selected', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" id="search_skills" name="search_skills[]">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">PHP</option>
    <option value="2">JAVA</option>
    <option value="3">.NET</option>
</select>
```

Comment: when clicking first time..all gets selected..but when un selecting..it again selects all..

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$('#search_skills option:first').on('click', function() {
var that = $(this);
  var opt = $('#search_skills > option');
  if (!that.is('selected')) {
    opt.prop('selected', true);
  }
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ud4q6L91/)